# android-support-v4.jar showing empty files

Tags: android, eclipse

I just add external jar(android support.v4.jar) to my project using eclipse IDE.

But it show empty packages.Can anyone guide me how to solve this.?

External jar show empty packages:

[image: external jar show empty packages]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just add external jar(android support.v4.jar) to my project using eclipse IDE.

Not quite. You added `support-v4-23.1.1-sources.jar`. The key part of that filename, with respect to your problem, is `sources`. This JAR contains Java source code, not compiled Java classes.

> Can anyone guide me how to solve this.?

Google is no longer supporting Eclipse. There is no official distribution of any of the support libraries as simple JARs, or even Eclipse-style library projects.

The simple solution is to move to Android Studio, or possibly IntelliJ IDEA, instead of using Eclipse.